# nodejs execute redis commands with delay

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, redis, sleep

I want to execute few `redis` operations from `nodejs` application with some given delay between each execution.

I am using [node_redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis) client. Node version `v8.10.0`

I thought of implementing it like below :

```
function func(id1, max){
    for(i=0; i < max; i++){       
        client.incr(id1, (error, value) => {
            if(error){
                console.log("redis incr failed : " + error);
                return error;
            }
            console.log("updated value : " + value);
        });
        sleep.sleep(1);
    }
    client.quit();
return("incr value ended for : " + id);    
}

func(id1, max);
```

But then in this case the complete `redis incr` happens in a stretch and the callback (`console.log("updated value : " + value"))` happens with delay. Note: for `sleep` in above code, I am using [sleep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sleep) package.
I also tried below solution (found after googling):

```
var delay = 1000; //1 second

for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        client.incr(id, (error, value) => {
            if(error){
                console.log("redis incr failed : " + error);
                return error;
            }
            console.log("updated value : " + value);
        });
    }, delay);
}
```

But it also behaves the same as above one.

Afaik, it is caused due to the nodejs being `synchronous` and (I think) the `node_redis` client being `async`.

**TL;DR**
What I want to do is, increment a key every n seconds in `redis` using `nodejs`.

Thanks in advance!
PS : I am beginner in `nodejs`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `for` loop executes and puts all the callbacks into callback queue with a delay of 1s. So just modify the `for` loop to this.

```
let delay = 1000; //1 second

for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        client.incr(id, (error, value) => {
            if(error){
                console.log("redis incr failed : " + error);
                return error;
            }
            console.log("updated value : " + value);
        });
    }, delay);
    delay += 1000;
}
```

Also please avoid using `var` and start using ES6 syntax which supports `const` and `let` and is hoisting safe.

Comment: this worked. But still don't understand how adding `delay += 1000` solved this ? Isn't the delay increasing by 1 second for the `for` loop itself in every iteration?

Comment: That's because of how the JavaScript's event loop works. The `for` loop is synchronous while `setTimeout` is asynchronous. The setTimeout doesn't delay the execution of the for loop. It just pushes the callback to be executed to the callback  queue of the event loop and proceeds with the for loop execution. Once for loop has finished executing it will start executing code from  callback queue. I suggest you to read event loop of JavaScript to have a clear understanding on how your JS code executes.